# Methods with @Scheduled annotation not working in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, scheduled-tasks

**tl;dr: Can you think of any case I could look for where `@Scheduled` tasks are not executed in a Spring Boot app?**

I implemented the [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) and it worked just fine, however, in a more complex Spring Boot app I am working on I can't get the `@Scheduled` methods to run.

My main class looks like this:

```
package com.mypackage.myapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class);
    }
}
```

and the component in which the scheduled app lives looks like this:

```
(...)

@Component
public class MyComponent {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyComponent.class);

    (...)

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void myScheduledTask() {
        logger.info("Executing scheduled task");

    (...)  
    }
}
```

The whole application is obviously more complex, but this is essentially it. Unfortunately, `"Executing scheduled task"` appears no where in the logs, also if I debug the breakpoint is never reached.

As I said, the minimal example works for me, however in my app it isn't. Can you think of any case I could check for where `@Scheduled` tasks are not executed? For example, can the configuration be overruled by anything? Can anything interfere?

I am using version `1.5.1.RELEASE`.

Comment: What is the package of MyComponent class?Can you make sure the MyComponent was "picked" to be initialized by Spring? You can check this my create a default constructor and add a log in it. Or you can try to use @ComponentScan to include its package

Comment: The component contains other, non-scheduled methods, and it works just fine. The whole app and every component in it, really. It's just the scheduled method that doesn't get executed.

Comment: Did you configure any TaskExecutor? If so, its thread pool may be full.

Comment: I think I figured it out, thanks @C-Otto . See my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I have another component that implements `SmartLifecycle`, and the `start()` method contains a `while` loop that I never get out of (intentionally, reading from a Kafka stream). This essentially leads to the initialization being stuck, and hence the `@Scheduled` method never actually being scheduled.

I could just reproduce that in a minimal example with a `while(true)`. As soon as I have that, the `@Scheduled` method doesn't get executed, when I remove the `while`, it works just fine.

```
package com.mypackage.myapp;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StartLoop implements SmartLifecycle {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartLoop.class);
    private static final int LAST_PHASE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private boolean running;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        runMyCode();
    }

    private void runMyCode() {
        running = true;
        log.info("Starting ...");
        while (running) {
            try {
                log.info("running");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        log.info("Stopping ...");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable callback) {
        callback.run();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return LAST_PHASE;
    }

}
```

If I now replace the `start()` method by

```
@Override
public void start() {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::runMyCode);
}
```

it works perfectly fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73279574/234110 is another way to overcome it

Comment: How is this a solution to the problem in my question?