# Why @Scheduled is not working in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I am trying to add scheduled job to my application.

I have created bean that has method annotated with `@Scheduled`. Also I have added `@EnableScheduling` to my `ApplicationConfig` class.

But it doesn't work. My application does not start as it starts usually,  and the application port does not open, and there is no stacktrace with errors.
Logs end with

`INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          [] : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'`

but not as usual with

`Started MyApp in 11.136 seconds`

Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class ApplicationConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Bean(name = "publisherPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor publishPoolTaskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("publisher-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}

@Component
public class JobService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobService.class);

   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000L)
    public void doWork() {
        log.info("Working...");
    }
}
```

Async is not used in my scheduler, it's for other purpose.

Logs that appear at the end

```
2022-08-08 16:43:35.112 [scheduling-1] INFO  o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-08 16:43:35.155 [scheduling-1] INFO  org.hibernate.Version                    [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2022-08-08 16:43:35.267 [scheduling-1] INFO  o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2022-08-08 16:43:35.347 [scheduling-1] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-08 16:43:35.389 [scheduling-1] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-08 16:43:35.406 [scheduling-1] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-08-08 16:43:35.572 [scheduling-1] WARN  org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder       [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HHH000457: Joined inheritance hierarchy [com.xxx.MyEntity] defined explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  Legacy Hibernate behavior was to ignore the @DiscriminatorColumn.  However, as part of issue HHH-6911 we now apply the explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  If you would prefer the legacy behavior, enable the `hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined` setting (hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true)
2022-08-08 16:43:36.131 [scheduling-1] INFO  o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       [traceId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, spanExportable=false, X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=40196fb09b21f5ba, X-B3-TraceId=40196fb09b21f5ba] : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

Code of the AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler:

```
public class CustomAsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAsyncExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(
        @NonNull Throwable ex,
        Method method,
        @NonNull Object... params) {
        log.error(
            String.format(
                "Error while executing async method [%s] with parameters [%s]: %s",
                method.getName(),
                Stream.of(params).map(Object::toString).collect(joining(",")),
                ex.getMessage()
            ),
            ex
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: *Started MyApp in 11.136 seconds* That is only a debug message, how long you app needs to be startet. This has nothing to do with the sceduler

Comment: @Jens well, after adding EnableScheduling, it disappeared for some reason. Also my API logic not works also(port 8080 was not opened)

Comment: Any errormessages in your logfile?

Comment: try changing value of `fixedDelay` to 1000 for debugging purpose and see if you get Working... somewhere in logs?

Comment: @Jens no error messages, just INFO and WARNs(jpa warnings). Application not exists with error

Comment: do you get this message `Tomcat started on ports(s): 8080` ?

Comment: Yes, I have `Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)` and also `Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]`, but last log is `Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'`.
@silentsudo

Comment: I have added last logs, that appear not with [main], but with [scheduling-1]
@silentsudo

Comment: Sorry, I dont have `Tomcat started on ports(s): 8080`, I only have with `initialized`

Comment: can create a simple spring boot project with same version and use this same code, a new project just to see if default are working or not?>

Comment: @silentsudo okey

Comment: Kinda sounds like the `CustomAsyncExceptionHandler` is swallowing some sort of exceptions.

Comment: @Apokralipsa added to topic the code, please take a look

Comment: @silentsudo yes it works with defaults in new application

Comment: comment out this bean definitions `publishPoolTaskExecutor`

Comment: I have added the same config and handler to new application, but Scheduled anno still works for me...)  @silentsudo

Comment: @silentsudo yes... I commented that bean definition and it works in my main application.
What is the problem? I have this bean for async logic, that is not related to my scheduled task

Comment: what happens when you remove this line `executor.initialize();`?

Comment: Logs are same as in initial version of code @silentsudo

Comment: The exception handler seems fine after all. Javadoc for `AsyncConfigurer` seems to suggest that classes implementing it are treated in a non standard way. Could you try creating a new config class and using only `@Configuration` and `@EnableScheduling` on it?

Comment: @Apokralipsa I've already tried to annotated main class, but it didn't help. I have tried creating new config class now - the same problem : )

Comment: maybe I should somehow tell to scheduler to not to use my custom publishPoolTaskExecutor?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm out of ideas at the moment in that case :(

Comment: @Apokralipsa seems I had to implement SchedulingConfigurer for some reason. Now it works

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented `SchedulingConfigurer` in my config and it works for me.

Example of configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler t = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        t.setPoolSize(1);
        t.setThreadNamePrefix("scheduler - ");
        t.initialize();
        return t;
    }
}
```